# How to run a .sh-script from any path in a terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I know how to run the script I created. But it is a matter of pain that I need to change directory through terminal and run my scripts.
I need to run the `slowloris` script, that has into Desktop, now change directory to Desktop and run.

Then I have another in root; now change the directory to root and run that.

My question is:
**How can I run any shell-script by just typing `./script` from any path** like we start Metasploit from any path by giving `msfconsole` from any path.

Comment: The easiest way is to choose a directory to hold your scripts (or softlinks to your scripts) and **make sure that is in your path**. On Linux, a logical choice is `/usr/local/bin`. Then simply make sure your scripts are executable (e.g. `chmod +x` <scriptname>).  (when choosing a `scriptname` it is advisable to check if any other program already uses the name with `which scriptname` or `type scriptname`) With the script location in your path, and it being executable, you can then simply run it from anywhere by typing `scriptname`

Comment: Shell scripts are "shell scripts", not ".sh scripts", and don't need to have file extensions. Bash scripts, in particular, should not use .sh extensions, as this extension implies that a script could be run with `sh scriptname.sh`, whereas any script with bash extensions is not guaranteed to run that way.

Comment: Typing `./script` from anywhere will *never* run a script that is anywhere other than your current directory (a.k.a. `./`). Even if there's something called `script` somewhere in your `PATH`, invoking `./script` will tell the shell "don't look in $PATH, I want to run the one that is right here", with the obvious consequence if there is not, in fact, such a script...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One option is simply to type the path to the script:

```
~/Desktop/script
```

This works fine, but gets a bit unwieldy.

This is what the `PATH` environment variable is for.  And it is what `$HOME/bin` is for.

1. Create yourself a directory `$HOME/bin`.  Put all your executable scripts in it (make them executable with `chmod +x script` if need be<sup>**††**</sup>).  This way, there's one place to look for the scripts you want to run.
2. Add `$HOME/bin` to your `PATH`.  I put mine at the front: `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH`, but you could put it at the back if you prefer.
3. Update your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` (or possibly `.bashrc`) file to set `PATH`.  Beware of a continually growing PATH, though.

As [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235154/how-to-run-a-sh-script-from-any-path-in-an-unix-terminal/29235240#comment46676729_29235240), once the command is installed in a directory on `PATH`, you no longer type `./script`, but just `script`.  This is exactly like you type `ls` and not `/bin/ls`, etc.  Once the program is installed in a directory on your `PATH`, it is (for many purposes) indistinguishable from a system-provided command.

I have about 500 scripts and programs in my `$HOME/bin` directory.

Note that this doesn't require any special privileges.  If you have administrator access to your machine and you think other users might find your commands useful, then you could install the scripts/programs in one of the system-provided directories on your `PATH`.  However, it is usually best not to add programs to any of:

- `/bin`
- `/usr/bin`
- `/sbin`
- `/usr/sbin`

There is often/usually `/usr/local/bin` which is a suitable place for widely used commands not provided by the system.

---

<sup>**††**</sup> It would be better to use `chmod a+x,go-w script`; your scripts should not be writable by other people.  You could even simply use `chmod 555 script` or `chmod 755 script`.  I tend to keep my scripts non-writable.  That way, I have to go through a formal change process with the version control system.  It means there's less danger of uncontrolled changes.

Comment: Though the syntax is obviously then `script` and not `./script`

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler has a very nice explanation. Indeed I think the best would be to add the script slowloris to your `$PATH` environment variable. In this way, you can run `slowloris` from anywhere without `./slowloris` (as ./ means 'run from this directory'). I wanted to point you to a nice example! https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path

Answer (score 3):

You have to copy or link the script into a directory that is on the $PATH. Usually `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin/` are on the path so these are good locations to link or copy the script to.

```
ln -s /path/to/your/script /usr/local/bin
```

If you are not root you will either need to `sudo` that command or run it as the root user.

Comment: I am getting an error "ln: /usr/local/bin: hard link not allowed for directory"

Comment: @NIKHILCM — If you are getting an error about hard links, it means you omitted the `-s` option.

Comment: Once, we create the softlink, we will not need type as `./script`, `script` will suffice